# Empty while loop hangs in iPhone release build

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason having an empty while loop in a release build hangs, while having it in the debug build works fine.  This example works in debug but hangs in release:

```
//Wait for stream to open
while (!_isReadyForData);
```

This is the solution I came up with in order to get it to work in release:

```
//Wait for stream to open
while (!_isReadyForData)
{
   //For some reason in release mode, this is needed
   sleep(.5);
}
```

I am just curious why I would need to add something in the loop block of code.

Comment: Please do not do either of these. The first one wastes a lot of CPU time simply waiting for something to happen. Use event driven logic. Don't just sit and wait.

Comment: Listen to the comment above. Nevertheless, regarding why this happens, I'm betting the release build is compiled with a higher optimization level, which probably sees no writes to "_isReadyForData" in the loop and optimizes it to an infinite empty busy-loop. In other languages, using "volatile" on the variable is usually required to force the compiler to go fetch the new value of _isReadyForData for every loop iteration. I'm not sure what the equivalent objective-c construct is.

Comment: @faffaffaff if by other languages you mean C, I'm happy to inform you that Objective-C is a thin layer of C, thus the `volatile` keyword is right there for you to be used ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Ah yes you're right. Not sure how it works with (auto-)synthesized properties and so on, though.

Comment: nothing special, trust me. In the end everything boils down to old plain C ;)

Comment: I know, but when you're auto-synthesizing you're actually not typing out any variable declaration, so I'm not sure where you'd stick the "volatile" keyword. Perhaps it requires a "manual" ivar declaration.

Comment: Never, ever, ever do a "wait loop" in UI code.  And before you next attempt anything even vaguely resembling this again, be sure you fully understand data synchronization and volatility.

Comment: @HotLicks Aside from the condescending remarks, my question was to the  "why" this doesn't work, not a lecture on when to use it.  I didn't mention anywhere that this was on a UI thread.

Comment: @faffaffaff Thanks for your comment - makes sense.  I didn't realize volatile was still valid in obj-c (don't know why I didn't think so).

Comment: @rmaddy This is just a test program for writing some low level bsd commands for doing some p2p - never intended on any of it going into a live app.

Comment: You are good, and found good thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is of course due to compilers optimizations, as already noted in the comments.

Remembering that Objective-C is built on top of C, I put together a simple C example with different levels of optimizations and here's the result.

#### Original code

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])  {
    char _isReadyForData = 0;
    while (!_isReadyForData);
    return 0;
}
```

#### LLVM IR with no optimizations (-O0)

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %argc.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %argv.addr = alloca i8**, align 8
  %_isReadyForData = alloca i8, align 1
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  store i32 %argc, i32* %argc.addr, align 4
  store i8** %argv, i8*** %argv.addr, align 8
  store i8 0, i8* %_isReadyForData, align 1
  br label %while.cond

while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.body, %entry
  %0 = load i8* %_isReadyForData, align 1
  %tobool = icmp ne i8 %0, 0
  %lnot = xor i1 %tobool, true
  br i1 %lnot, label %while.body, label %while.end

while.body:                                       ; preds = %while.cond
  br label %while.cond

while.end:                                        ; preds = %while.cond
  ret i32 0
}
```

#### LLVM IR with level 1 optimizations (-O1)

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) #0 {
entry:
  br label %while.cond

while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.cond, %entry
  br label %while.cond
}
```

As you can see, the compiler produces an infinite loop when optimizing, since the local variable `_isReadyForData` is useless in that context and therefore is removed.

As suggested by @faffaffaff, using the `volatile` keyword on `_isReadyForData` may solve the issue.

#### LLVM IR with level 1 optimizations (-O1) with volatile keyword

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) #0 {
entry:
  %_isReadyForData = alloca i8, align 1
  store volatile i8 0, i8* %_isReadyForData, align 1
  br label %while.cond

while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.cond, %entry
  %_isReadyForData.0.load1 = load volatile i8* %_isReadyForData, align 1
  %lnot = icmp eq i8 %_isReadyForData.0.load1, 0
  br i1 %lnot, label %while.cond, label %while.end

while.end:                                        ; preds = %while.cond
  ret i32 0
}
```

But I definitely agree with @rmaddy in saying that you'd better change the flow of your program and use driven logic, instead of patching what you have already.